# get wrong date for my databind method

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, sql-server-2008, visual-studio-2012

I have a page where the user can enter "from date" and "to date" and get a set of values based on the date-intervall. The only problem is that it isn't working with the "to date".
When I enter something like this: `from: 2012-01-01 | to: 2013-07-26` it works fine. But when I try something like this: `from: 2010-07-04 | to: 2012-01-01` I still get all results AFTER that date aswell (like from 2013).

I've run a debug using the input values above (2010/07/04-2012/01/01). Here is my code along with the relevant values from the debug:

**ASPX**

```
    <asp:TextBox ID="VolumeSearchFromDate" runat="server" CssClass="dateTextBox" />
    <br />
    <asp:TextBox ID="VolumeSearchToDate" runat="server" CssClass="dateTextBox" />
    <br />
    <asp:Button ID="Button2" runat="server" Text="Search" onclick="btnVolumeSearch_Click" ValidationGroup="validate" />
    <br />
    <asp:GridView ID="myGv" runat="server" 
    ShowFooter="True" 
    AutoGenerateColumns="False" AllowSorting="True" DataKeyNames="id" DataSourceID="myObjectDataSource" >
        <Columns>
            //my columns here
        </Columns>
    </asp:GridView>

<asp:ObjectDataSource ID="myObjectDataSource" runat="server" 
        DeleteMethod="myDeleteMethod" SelectMethod="mySelectMethod" 
        TypeName="whereItsAt.sqlDataLayer" UpdateMethod="myUpdateMethod">
        <DeleteParameters>
            <asp:Parameter Name="id" Type="Int32" />
        </DeleteParameters>
        <SelectParameters>
            <asp:Parameter Name="fromDate" Type="DateTime"/>
            <asp:Parameter Name="toDate" Type="DateTime"/>
        </SelectParameters>
        <UpdateParameters>
            <asp:Parameter Name="id" Type="Int32" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="volume" Type="Int32" />
        </UpdateParameters>
    </asp:ObjectDataSource>
```

**Code behind (c#)**

```
//dont know why this is here. The person who wrote the code 
//in the first place wrote this and I haven't removed it.
protected void btnVolumeSearch_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{
    gvVolumeListBindData();
}

private void gvVolumeListBindData()
{
    myObjectDataSource.SelectParameters.Remove(myObjectDataSource.SelectParameters["fromDate"]);
    string debugString /* "" */= VolumeSearchFromDate.Text.ToString(); /* 2010-04-07 */
    string debugString2 /* 2012-01-01 */ = debugString /* "" */;
    myObjectDataSource.SelectParameters.Add("fromDate", VolumeSearchFromDate.Text.ToString());
    myObjectDataSource.SelectParameters.Remove(myObjectDataSource.SelectParameters["toDate"]);
    myObjectDataSource.SelectParameters.Add("toDate", VolumeSearchToDate.Text.ToString());
    debugString /* "" */ = VolumeSearchToDate.Text.ToString(); /* 2012-01-01
    debugString2 /* 2012-01-01 */ = debugString; /* "" */

    gvVolumeList.DataBind();
}
```

**Method for retrieving data (also C#)**

```
public static DataTable mySelectMethod(DateTime fromDate /* 2010-07-04 00:00:00 */, DateTime toDate /* 2013-07-26 00:00:00 */)
{
    DateTime minDate = new DateTime(1900,01,01,00,00,00);
    DateTime maxDate = DateTime.Today;

    int result = DateTime.Compare(minDate, fromDate);

    if (result >= 0)
    {
        fromDate = minDate;
    }

    result = DateTime.Compare(maxDate, toDate);

    if (result >= 0)
    {
        toDate = maxDate;
    }

    //set up connection, call stored procedure etc etc etc.

    return table;
}
```

So do anyone understand what's going on here? Seems to me that my variables just randomly change values from time to time.

**EDIT**
The problem was that I was only checking if fromDate was too small and if toDate was to big, but I needed to check both. Thanks to Md. Parvez Alam and Can Canbek for helping me get to that conclusion :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change this line

```
result = DateTime.Compare(maxDate, toDate);
```

to

```
result = DateTime.Compare(toDate, maxDate);
```

go through this link

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.compare.aspx

Comment: I thought so too, but when I do, the if-statement isn't entered and i get `SqlDateTime overflow. Must be between 1/1/1753 12:00:00 AM and 12/31/9999 11:59:59 PM.`

Comment: please try like this result = DateTime.Compare(toDate, DateTime.Now);

Comment: Oh! On a seccond debug I realized that I compare if the toDate is Larger than todays date, but the fact is that it is SMALLER than the minimum allowed date! I still get the wrong value though... should be `2012-01-01` and not `0001-01-01`

Comment: please try the above option

Comment: I got it to work now :P I just had to check if both variables were either smaller or bigger instead of just checking if fromDate was too small and toDate was too big

Answer (score 1):

Ok let's go step by step;

You have your minDate value and maxDate value which is today.

```
 result = DateTime.Compare(maxDate, toDate);

    if (result >= 0)
    {
        toDate = maxDate;
    }
```

When you get to this part, you compare today's date with the toDate variable, and since today's date is after your toDate value it returns "1" and you assign today's date to toDate value thus returning today's date.

I think if you switch the code with this, it should work

```
 result = DateTime.Compare(maxDate, toDate);

    if (result < 0)
    {
        toDate = maxDate;
    }
```

So if the input is actually after today's date you turn the input into today's date.

Comment: As I answered Md. Parvez Alam, I tried this at first because that was what it looked like on MSDN-documentation. But when I do it like this I get this error: `SqlDateTime overflow. Must be between 1/1/1753 12:00:00 AM and 12/31/9999 11:59:59 PM.` because the If-statement is never entered

Comment: then you should add an else statement to it and return the original toDate value